# ATUALIZAÇÃO DE PEMISSÂO DE CANAL DE TEXTO DISCORD

Tags: javascript

Boa Tarde.

Estou fazendo um BOT para Discord, e quero criar um canal de texto e então gerenciar as permissões do mesmo.

Porém, na hora de atualizar as permissões, não está atualizando.
Já garanti que o BOT esta como ADM do servidor.

Segue código:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
exports.run = async (client, message, args, db, civs) => {
const content = args.join(" ");
message.delete();


//if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission('MANAGE_CHANNELS')) return message.channel.send('Não tenho permissão de gerenciar canais')
//if (message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name.includes(message.author.id))) return message.reply('Já existe um canal criado pra você ')

if (!args[0]) {
    return message.channel.send(`<@${message.author.id}>, escreva a denúncia após o comando`);
  } else if (content.length > 1000) {
    return message.channel.send(`<@${message.author.id}>, forneça uma denúncia de no máximo 1000 caracteres. Caso precise de mais caracteres, continue escrevendo depois de fazer a denúncia primária.`);
  } else {


let channel // declarando variavel global channel que é o canal que vai ser criado e marcado a pessoa que deu comando
try { // ← Tentar criar o canal, se nao conseguir cai no catch
    channel = await message.guild.channels
        .create(`den•┋${message.member.displayName}|`,{
            type: 'text',
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                 id: '729790119388905552', // everyone
                 deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'], // permissoes de nao ver o canal (ler mensagens)
            },
            {
                  id: message.author.id, // permissoes para quem digitou o comando
                  allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'], // essa pessoa pode ver o canal e enviar mensagens
            },
            {
                  id: '740149831825358848',  // Moderador
                  allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'] // essa pessoa pode ver o canal e enviar mensagens
            },
            ],
        });
        channel.setParent('774700250953940992');         
    }
catch(err) {
    message.channel.send('Erro: ' + err.message);
}

    let timeout = await channel.send(`<@${message.author.id}>`);// espera o canal ser criado e marca o membro

    // Envia conteúdo da mensagem no canal criado.
    const msg = await channel.send(
       new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       .setColor("#FFFFF1")
       .addField("Autor:", message.author)
       .addField("Conteúdo", content)
       .setFooter("ID do Autor: " + message.author.id)
       .setTimestamp()
     );
}}

exports.config = {
name: 'denuncia',
aliases: ['denuncia']
}
```

Basicamente, quero que apenas o autor e os moderadores possam ver esta canal de texto.
Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema.

Ocorre que usar a ID de everyone não foi efetivo. Assim, achei uma saída, que é:

```
const cargo_todos = message.guild.roles.cache.find((cargo_todos) => {
    return cargo_todos.name === '@everyone'
})

let channel // declarando variavel global channel que é o canal que vai ser criado e marcado a pessoa que deu comando
try { // ← Tentar criar o canal, se nao conseguir cai no catch
    channel = await message.guild.channels
        .create(`den•┋${message.member.displayName}|`,{
            type: 'text',
            parent: '774683424551600178',
            permissionOverwrites: [
            {
                 id: cargo_todos.id, // Everyone
                 deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES']
            },
```

Com isso, o BOT funcionou corretamente.

Answer (score -2):

Não tenho a certeza se é isto que você procura, mas apesar de estar a tentar criar um canal dentro de um try/catch eu acho que quando você cria o canal com o `await message.guild.chanels.create()` têm de atribuir as permissões depois de o canal ser criado e não na altura em que ele é criado, uma solução para isto é adicionar um `.then` e um `.catch()` ao objeto **channel**

Porém não tenho a certeza se o código que vou postar em baixo irá funcionar pois nunca tentei criar canais como forma de reportar utilizadores. Por norma é criado um canal na categoria de administração do servidor para onde o BOT envia todos os reports que são feitos e não é criado um canal independente para cada report.
Mas vou deixar as duas referências de onde tirei esta conclusão no fim da resposta, outra opção boa é sempre consultar a documentação oficial do Discord.js [aqui](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome), eu sei que às vezes pode parecer um bocado confusa mas basta pesquisar os métodos que queremos aplicar na barra de pesquisa, por norma estes dizem tudo aquilo que tal método é capaz de criar e como o utilizar.

```
let channel; // declarando variavel global channel que é o canal que vai ser criado e marcado a pessoa que deu comando
channel = await message.guild.channels
  .create(`den•┋${message.member.displayName}|`, {
    type: "text",
  })
  .then((channel) => {
    channel.setParent("774700250953940992");
    channel.permissionOverwrites([
      {
        id: "729790119388905552", // everyone
        deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"], // permissoes de nao ver o canal (ler mensagens)
      },
      {
        id: message.author.id, // permissoes para quem digitou o comando
        allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL", "SEND_MESSAGES"], // essa pessoa pode ver o canal e enviar mensagens
      },
      {
        id: "740149831825358848", // Moderador
        allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL", "SEND_MESSAGES"], // essa pessoa pode ver o canal e enviar mensagens
      },
    ]);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Outros links que podem ajudar:
[Video no Youtube que mostra como criar canais com Discord.js v12](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKp9rd3jyis)
(Pessoalmente eu usei a playlist desse criador para criar o meu Bot, mas pode exister sempre maneiras melhores)

Espero que ajude

Comment: Não é exatamente isto.
O problema está em definir a restrição ao @everyone.

Comment: Já experimentou em vez de restringir o acesso a @everyone de uma forma global, usar as permissoes integradas no Discord.js de forma a criar um canal que só pessoas com a permissão `MANAGE_GUILD`, por exemplo, conseguem ver? As permissoes do discord servem para facilitar esse tipo de situações, pois não deve de usar uma menção (@everyone) que **engloba literalmente todos os utilizadores do servidor** administradores incluidos, de facto a minha resposta não é a mais acertada mas voçê deveria utilizar as permissoes embutidas no discord para este tipo de coisas como a documentação diz